# Dynamic Form Elements Population Laravel 5 Blade

Tags: forms, laravel-5, dynamic-forms

I have created a form where a user can add elements depending on the number of names needed. My code is as follows

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-3 form-group-sm">
            {!! form::label('first_name[]', 'First Name: ') !!}
            {{--{!! form::text('first_name[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'First Name']) !!}--}}
            <input type="text" name="first_name[]" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-3 form-group-sm">
            {!! form::label('middle_name[]', 'Middle Name[s]: ') !!}
            {{--{!! form::text('middle_name[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Middle Name[s]']) !!}--}}
            <input type="text" name="middle_name[]" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Middle Name[s]">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-3 form-group-sm">
            {!! form::label('last_name[]', 'Last Name: ') !!}
            {{--{!! form::text('last_name[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Last Name']) !!}--}}
            <input type="text" name=last_name[]" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-success add_field_button"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Add Another Person (Max 5)</button>
```

When the form fails it's validation it should return to the original form, display validation errors and re-populate the form.

Obviously this needs to loop though the returned values but I am unable to get the returned form content for these elements.

I can dump out the errors but not sure how to get the returned form element values :(

Comment: how did you implement adding the dynamic fields?